# How to use the templates in a method parameter in a class

Tags: c++, class, templates

I have a problem when use the templates with a method parameter inside a class.
The following is an example but not my real code which has the problem, in order to simplify the code.

**Class declaration:**

```
class Test {

public:
    Test();
    template <class T>
    void PrintData(T info);
};
```

**Class definition:**

```
Test::Test(){}

void Test::PrintData(T info){
    cout << info << endl;
}
```

**When usage:**

```
int main(){
    Test test;
    test.PrintData<const char*>("Thank you.");

    return 0;
}
```

**The error messages:**

- variable or field 'PrintData' declared void
- 'T' was not declared in this scope

**What is the problem in my code, and/or how to use the templates with the method parameter correctly ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template<typename T>
void Test::PrintData(T info){
```

would be the correct definition of that function. Along with that include definitions also in header.

Answer (score 0):

in class definition section where u defied your `PrintData` function, reference of template is required

so your definition will be like this
    
    `template <class T>
    void Test::PrintData(T info){
        cout << info << endl;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the definition of the template member function in the header file and it should work fine.

header:

```
#include <iostream>

class Test 
{
public:
    Test();
    template <class T>
    void PrintData(T info);
};

template <class T>
void Test::PrintData(T info)
{
    std::cout << info << std::endl;
}
```